# Access Windows localhost:8080 from Ubuntu running on VirtualBox/VMWare

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have to test my web application on Safari and the closest WebKit based browser I can find is GNOME Web (formerly Ephiphany) which is available on Ubuntu. I'm running my Quarkus application on my windows machine on localhost port 8080 and I need to be able to access this IP & port from Ubuntu running on the VM (in the ephiphany browser URL). I've come across multiple posts giving solutions but they don't really seem to work - some say firewalls are blocking it and so on (Not sure what is the latest information). Could someone please help out with the correct networking parameters? TIA!

I'm open to using both VirtualBox or VMWare for my testing purposes.

The solutions I've tried don't reach the Windows locahost. I've tried switching between NAT or bridged adapters but I'm probably missing something somewhere.

Comment: The real issue seems to be that you want "localhost" to reference the Windows host. This should work automagically in WSL, but for regular VMs you will need (1) a bridged adapter and (2) to either use the IP or to set "localhost" to the Windows IP in the hosts file.

Comment: Assuming either NAT or Bridged network connections in the guest (not Host Only) you should be able to access the other machine by IP address. To run a Browser on the Windows Host  (that is to run an App), you may need to RDP into the machine to use it. I have done both the above here.

Comment: Is there any link you could provide that contains the steps?

Comment: Map a folder on Windows from Linux:   SMB://IPaddress/folder  .  This maps a connection on Windows.   

RDP:   Use RDP on Linux and access the Windows Machine to run an App on the Windows machine.